# Prove linear independence of $1/x$, $1/(x+1)$,$\ldots$, $1/(x+n)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove linear independence of $1/x$, $1/(x+1)$,$\ldots$, $1/(x+n)$.

I wanted to show this by induction. Assume $\alpha_01/x+...+\alpha_n 1/(x+n)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha_0=...=\alpha_n=0$ and then use this in order to show $\alpha_0/x+...+\alpha_{n+1}/(x+n+1)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha_0=...=\alpha_{n+1}=0$. But this is already where I can't proceed. Does anyone have any suggestoins how to prove this

Comment: Hint: None of $1/(x+1), 1/(x+2), \ldots, 1/(x+n)$ have an asymptote at $0$.

Comment: Hint for your specific approach: multiply through by $x+n+1$ and then substitute $x=-n-1$ into the resulting equation.

Comment: I cant see it. If I multiply by $x+n+1$ I just get a horrible expression. And why should it be useful to note that we dont have an assymptote?

Comment: I think I have an other solution. Assume by contradiction that $1/x$,...$1/(x+n)$ are linearly dependent and then we could find $\alpha_0 1/x+...\alpha_{n}1/(x+n)=0$ let's substitute $x=1$ but then we have found a linear combination of real numbers over rational numbers but this doesnt work since we konw that $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite dimensional

Comment: @Iwan5050 You would have simply found a finite collection of linearly dependent vectors in $\mathbb R_{\mathbb Q}$.  You haven't contradicted with infinite dimensionality.

Comment: I just realized this lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my hint didn't help, I will answer.

First, there is some subtlety here regarding the space containing these functions. It's not specified in the question. It can't be the space of functions from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$, because these are not functions from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$; they are undefined at certain non-positive integers. If you consider them instead as partial functions of $\Bbb{R}$ (i.e. functions whose domain is a subset of $\Bbb{R}$), then this no longer forms a vector space with respect to usual addition/scalar multiplication (if we added, say, $\sqrt{x - 1}$ and $\sqrt{-x}$ together, we would get an empty domain, and the empty function has no additive inverse).

I'm guessing that the space containing these functions is something along the lines of $C((0, \infty), \Bbb{R})$ (the space of continuous functions with domain $(0, \infty)$, whose codomain is $\Bbb{R}$) or some variation thereon. Specifically, a space of functions (continuity/smoothness optional) on some non-trivial interval containing only positive numbers.

Unfortunately, this is not ideal for my hint to work. I would prefer if our vector space were the space of real partial functions whose domain is cofinite, meaning that the complement of the domain is a finite set. This is a vector space, containing all of the given functions (each has a domain of all of $\Bbb{R}$ except just one point, and linear combinations of these functions are defined everywhere except the finite set $\{0, -1, \ldots, -n\}$).

Given this, we can analyse asymptotes. As I hinted, $(x+1)^{-1}, (x+2)^{-1}, \ldots, (x+n)^{-1}$ do not have asymptotes at $x = 0$, however, $x^{-1}$ does. What this tells me is that
$$x^{-1} \notin \operatorname{span}((x+1)^{-1}, (x+2)^{-1}, \ldots, (x+n)^{-1});$$
given any linear combination of $(x+1)^{-1}, (x+2)^{-1}, \ldots, (x+n)^{-1}$, the limit as $x \to 0^+$ will be finite (due to linearity of the limit), but this is not true of $x^{-1}$.

So, if $((x+1)^{-1}, (x+2)^{-1}, \ldots, (x+n)^{-1})$ is linearly independent, then the above implies that $(x^{-1}, (x+1)^{-1}, (x+2)^{-1}, \ldots, (x+n)^{-1})$ is linearly independent too. This is the basis for the inductive step. Or, indeed, one could look first at $\lim\limits_{{x \to -n^+}}$ instead of $\lim\limits_{{x \to 0^+}}$ in order to strip off $(x + n)^{-1}$. Either way, induction works: if the slightly shorter list is linearly independent, then the longer list is too.

Now, if we consider the space to be $C((0, \infty), \Bbb{R})$, this technique doesn't work as stated, because $\lim_{x \to -k^+}$ is meaningless for $k > 1$. We can still show $x^{-1}$ is not in the span of the other functions, but after that, all of the other functions are bounded on $(0, \infty)$! This does pose a serious limitation of this method, unfortunately.

So, we just need to show that $((x+1)^{-1}, (x+2)^{-1}, \ldots, (x+n)^{-1})$ is linearly independent. Since each function has a finite limit as $x \to 0^+$, we can uniquely extend these functions to the domain $[0, \infty)$, in a way that preserves linear combinations. I suggest looking at the right-derivatives of the functions at $0$ (note: it's the right-derivative, since the functions have no value to the left of $0$). Essentially, we can use a Wronskian argument.

We have
$$\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^m}{\mathrm{d}x^m} (x + k)^{-1}\right|_{x=0} = \frac{(-1)^m}{k^{-m}}m!,$$
So, the Wronskian for these functions at $0$ will be
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1!}{1} & \frac{1!}{2} & \frac{1!}{3} & \cdots & \frac{1!}{n} \\
-\frac{2!}{1^2} & -\frac{2!}{2^2} & -\frac{2!}{3^2} & \cdots & -\frac{2!}{n^2} \\
\frac{3!}{1^3} & \frac{3!}{2^3} & \frac{3!}{3^3} & \cdots & \frac{3!}{n^3} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
(-1)^n\frac{n!}{1^n} & (-1)^n\frac{n!}{2^n} & (-1)^n\frac{n!}{3^n} & \cdots & (-1)^n\frac{n!}{n^n}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
It suffices to show that this matrix has non-zero determinant. If we divide the rows of this matrix by various non-zero constants, then we obtain:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{1} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n} \\
\frac{1}{1^2} & \frac{1}{2^2} & \frac{1}{3^2} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n^2} \\
\frac{1}{1^3} & \frac{1}{2^3} & \frac{1}{3^3} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n^3} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{1}{1^n} & \frac{1}{2^n} & \frac{1}{3^n} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n^n}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
This matrix has zero determinant if and only if the previous matrix does. However, this matrix is a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), or at least the transpose of one, and has non-zero determinant because $1/1, 1/2, \ldots, 1/n$ are distinct real numbers.

So, as you can see, depending on the choice of underlying space, this is quite elementary, or it's not so much.